# Preventing Assignment of the Same In-App Purchase Subscription to Multiple User Accounts in an iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I'm developing an iOS app with an internal account system and integrated Apple in-app purchases. Users can create accounts with any email and make purchases through their Apple ID. Apple mandates a restore button for subscriptions, which I implemented using transactions.currententitlements. However, I face a challenge: a user might purchase a subscription with one account (e.g., new@gmail.com) and later restore it on another device with a different account (e.g., new2@gmail.com).

How can I track these subscriptions in my database to prevent multiple account associations with the same Apple in-app purchase? Is there a specific, unchanging field in the receipt data that is unique to the user's Apple ID, allowing me to track and update the correct account in my database when a restore occurs? I'm currently using the receipt for verification but need a reliable way to link these transactions to individual users, despite different emails used in my app.

Note: Apple rejected my app and asking me to provide a restore button even though I explained this to them.

Comment: You can try ATT or the VendorID or transaction ID or account token

Comment: You can link the original transaction identifier to a user in your database. If a different user tries to activate a subscription with that same original transaction identifier then you can either refuse to activate the subscription or update your database to remove the subscription from the other user and activate it on the new user.

Comment: does the orginalTransactionID never change?